# how to add space between two characters in jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I add space between `Hello` and `World`?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").text("Hello world!");
    });
});
```

P.S (&nbsp dosent work).

FIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/qj58Lm5q/8/

Comment: It already contains a space. To add more spaces use `&nbsp;` with `html()`. Ex. `$("p").html("Hello&nbsp;&nbsp;world!");`

Comment: @guradio what difference are you expecting that to make?

Comment: Well, yes, but there already is one. I assume the OP means multiple spaces. Also note that appending string literals to each other is bad practice, and just shows that the developer wasn't paying enough attention to their code.

Comment: I also said to use `html()`. [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/qj58Lm5q/9/)

Comment: Right, but my main point is that there already is one in his example. Your code makes no difference to that.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) like this:

```
$("p").html("Hello&nbsp;&nbsp;world!");
```

Read about [*`&nbsp;`*](http://www.sightspecific.com/~mosh/www_faq/nbsp.html)

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qj58Lm5q/10/)

Comment: Thanks :)

I was using text() insteat of html() and Confusing myself.

Comment: Yes @AkshayGupta you can refer link for reference for `html()` and `text()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("p").html('Hello<div style="width:50px; display:inline-block;"></div> world!');
```